# Task engine for Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabbitmq

We have an application that needs to perform lots of short background tasks (each might schedule more). In the future we might need to run the tasks on multiple servers.

We also need the tasks (and their parameters) to be persistent (stored in a DB) and be able to monitor tasks (status / logs /etc)

Is there a ready made solution that works with Ruby ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811931/how-to-manage-and-queue-background-jobs/1812013#1812013 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388016/spinning-background-tasks-in-rails http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606028/running-multiple-background-parallel-jobs-with-rails/1606141#1606141

Answer (score 1):

You can try [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) or [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque).