# How do I launch multiple rakes in parallel from a ruby script

Tags: ruby, rake

I have a ruby script from which I want to launch 4 rake tasks to run in parallel.

How do I do this?  I think I'll need to Fork and detach a process but I need the exact syntax.

Answer (score 16):

It's better if you let Rake handle the parallelism. You can do that using "multitask." Inside the Rakefile:

```
desc "Start everything."
multitask :start => [ 'mongodb:start', 'haystack:start' ]
```

[Background and source.](http://ozmm.org/posts/rake_start.html)

Otherwise, presuming you are doing this from outside the Rakefile, you could use horrid code like this, which would not throw exceptions as you might expect, and could easily fail in a number of ways:

```
require 'rake'
load 'Rakefile'

def invoke(name)
  Thread.new do
    puts Rake::application[name].invoke
  end
end

invoke :make_coffee
invoke :boil_eggs
invoke :empty_trash
```

(so don't do that)

Comment: I really don't like this as a solution.  That works fine as long as that particular entrypoint is used to kick off the build; however, just to beat a dead horse (the `-j` option): with `make` I can select any target I want (eg, give an explicit path for a particular library to be built as opposed to specifying one of the convenience targets the build maintainer added) ... so long as I supply the `-j` option it builds in parallel.  It looks as though this particular solution would only work as long as you have something in place to use `multitask` anywhere it could potentially be needed.

Comment: @BrianVandenberg check out the `--multitask` command line option, it makes it so all tasks are treated as multitasks.

Answer (score 3):

use https://github.com/grosser/parallel

Parallel.each(data, :in_processes => 4) { |x| ruby_function(x) }

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `Multithreading`:

> http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_threads.html

also here was discussion on SO:

> [Running multiple background parallel jobs with Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606028/running-multiple-background-parallel-jobs-with-rails)

Answer (score 1):

make has a similar feature (-j) which allows you to run multiple tasks in parallel.

there is a pull request open to have this feature available in rake:
https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/pull/113

and a fork of rake with -j implemented: 
https://github.com/quix/rake